# can every iterative algorithm be turned into dynamic programming?

Tags: language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

It have been much discussed that every recursive algorithm can be transformed into iterative algorithms..

But... can every iterative algorithm be transformed into dynamic programming?

I'm starting to learn about Dynamic Programming... and i'm having a lot of problems.. even though i can find recursive solutions, and i'm expertising turning them into iterative algorithms, i still can't turn these iterative algorithms into dynamic programming... it'd be, indeed, very helpfull to certainly know that every iterative algorithm can be transformed into dynamic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that by Dynamic Programming you mean [the same thing as Wikipedia does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) - that is, algorithms that break the problem into smaller subproblems, and use memoization to avoid having to solve the same problem twice.

Dynamic Programming cannot be usefully applied to all iterative algorithms. For Dynamic Programming to be useful, the problem needs two properties:

1. Overlapping subproblems - when solving the problem recursively, you need to encounter the same subproblem, with the same parameters, more than once, otherwise memoizing was a waste of time and memory.
2. Optimal substructure - the knowledge that if you have the solutions to the sub-problems, the solution to the whole problem is easy to compute.

Comment: yes, i meant wikipedia's concept of dynamic programming. Thanks! it's really helpfull to know that.